# Visual Studio 2015 and XamarinVS 3.9. -"Connection to the layout rendered failed"

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am attempting to create a Cross Platform application for a Android and iOS but I can't resolve this error.

> Connection to the layout rendered failed. This may be caused by a
>   misconfiguration of of Java

**Current software installed:**

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Visual Studio Professional 2015
- JDK 1.8.0.101

ERROR:

> A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option
>   MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0 Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS:
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=256m Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0 Exception
>   in thread "main"

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to the tool option in Visual-studio IDE

*Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings -> Android SDK Location*

2.Change the Android SDK Location to "*C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Android\sdk*"

**Old location:**
*C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\MonoForAndroid\AndroidSDK*

**New location:**
*C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Android\sdk*

3.Restart the IDE.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks. Look like the SDK location is defined in many variables.